# electron-forge make failing

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I have failures in the packaging of my app using electron-forge, like the one below that I don't know what causes them:

`electron-forge make
✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
⠹ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-main.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
⠸ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-prefix.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
Failed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/flow.html
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
⠼ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/renderer.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"`

Answer (score 1):

Through a process of elimination, I have tracked down the problem to be depending on the contents of my electronPackagerConfig ignored files list

`"electronPackagerConfig": {
        "dir": "./src",
        "ignore": []`

If the ignore file list contains "lib", you get errors similar to this:

`electron-forge make
✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
⠹ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-main.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
⠸ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-prefix.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
Failed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/flow.html
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
⠴ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/renderer.js
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src"
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
Making for the following targets:
✔ Making for target: dmg - On platform: darwin - For arch: x64`

if your ignore file list contains "target", then you get failures like this:

`electron-forge make
✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
⠹ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-main.js
Cannot find module './targets-parser' (While processing preset: "/private/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js")
⠸ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/electron-prefix.js
Cannot find module './targets-parser' (While processing preset: "/private/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js")
Failed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/flow.html
Cannot find module './targets-parser' (While processing preset: "/private/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js")
⠴ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: /var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/renderer.js
Cannot find module './targets-parser' (While processing preset: "/private/var/folders/ld/v4nwzxnj7rq41_f08r5_clgw0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/flow-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js")
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
Making for the following targets:
✔ Making for target: dmg - On platform: darwin - For arch: x64`

I tried using "./lib" and "./target" with no change.

Reading the docs (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md) more closely, all these strings are in fact regexes and I think it will not be interpreting the "." as CWD.

It seems that escaping the "." to avoid it in the regex fixes this:

`"\\./target"`

The problem is now that those subfolders are not excluded from my package. 
I'm trying to find a regex that will exclude them, but not break the packager.